# how to use loop and how save the value in new variable

Tags: python-3.x

Note:My scenario is if suspect is detected with 'Height':3,'Colour':'Fair','resident':'Pune' 
condition the name should be save and code should be continue running,it mean  'Please enter 
your name' and 'Please Enter Height' continue ask.

```
suspect = {'Height':6,'Colour':'Fair','Residency':'Pune'}
      Name = input('Please enter your name')
      Verification = int(input('Please enter Height ')
      if Verification == suspect['Height']:
      print('Suspect is detected  for 1st level')
      else:
      print('Suspect is not detected  for 1st level')**
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop to get info from user, and will keep building characteristics as long as each additional characteristic matches those of the suspect.  If all the criteria (height, colour, residency) match the suspect then it will store the current person and info to a list of dictionaries.

When you enter 'q' or 'Q' for the Name, it will quit the loop and finish up by printing the list of names (and criteria) that match the description of the suspect.

If this is not exactly what you meant, you certainly have enough here to alter it to suit your taste:

```
class Suspects():

    def __init__(self, name, height, colour, residency):
        self.dictionary = {
            'Name': name,
            'Height': height,
            'Colour': colour,
            'Residency': residency
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name:' + str(self.dictionary['Name']) + ' Height:' + str(self.dictionary['Height']) + ' Colour:' + self.dictionary['Colour'] + ' Residency:' + self.dictionary['Residency']

# Create a 'Suspect'
suspect_list = []
suspect = Suspects('Suspect',6,'Fair','Pune')
print(suspect)

# loop until not same characteristics as 'Suspect'
while True:
    name = input('Please enter Name (Q|q to Quit): ')
    if name.lower() == 'q':
        break
    height = int(input('Please enter Height: '))
    if height == suspect.dictionary['Height']:
        print('Suspect matches height')
        colour = input('Please enter Colour: ')
        if colour == suspect.dictionary['Colour']:
            print('Suspect matches colour')
            residency = input('Please enter Residency: ')
            if residency == suspect.dictionary['Residency']:
                print('Suspect matches residency')
                print('*** THIS COULD BE OUR SUSPECT ***')
                suspect_list.append(Suspects(name,height,colour,residency))
            else:
                print('Suspect does NOT match residency')
                continue
        else:
            print('Suspect does NOT match colour')
            continue
    else:
        print('Suspect does NOT match height')
        continue

for i in suspect_list:
    print (i)
```

Comment: You could use a named tuple rather than a class, by the way

Comment: cricket_007, that would work in the solution I provided which has no need for mutability, but I fully expect my code to be changed to some degree by the original questioner and It is unclear whether an immutable solution will be amenable to the exact needs / preferences of said questioner.  I believe the recordclass is mutable as per the docs here https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/ and the questioner is welcome to explore this option.

Comment: Darshan Shinde, if you like the solution then please check it to accept it and also give it an up arrow.  That's how we earn enough reputation points to unlock features.  Thank you!